# What is the most efficient way to check if a C++ container is empty?

Tags: c++, stl

Which of the following is most efficient to check whether a container is empty?
Assume 'c' is any container part of the C++ Containers library

```
1. c.begin()==c.end()
2. c.empty() 
3. c.size()==0
```

In case of 2, the documentation reads "**Checks** if the container has no elements, i.e. whether begin() == end()" but **does not** state whether empty() is **implemented** as begin() == end(). So, how exactly is empty() implemented?

Why is this wrong?

```
sizeof(c) == 0
```

Comment: because `sizeof` is the size of the object not the count of the elements, also please don't post your quiz/homework questions here without showing your current attempts and understanding

Comment: Calling `empty()` is going to make the intent obvious to anyone reading the code, and I doubt the others would be any more efficient.

Comment: As you can see, with several questions by question, not all are answered.

Comment: How `empty()` is implemented is an implementation detail that may vary depending on who provides your standard library implementation.  You can't count on its performance being consistent across all compilers on all platforms. But it's likely to be cheap. Prefer it unless/until your profiling indicates it's a bottleneck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All three options to check for empty container are more or less equivalent. Using `empty()` shows (as denoted in the comments already) most obviously your intention and as a little bonus, it is even the shortest one to write (that's for the lazy ones like me...).

How it is implemented? Vendor specific, probably inlined. Option 1 being used for is not unlikely, but not guaranteed.

Classes are more or less a collection of data of whatever appropriate type. Their internal structure *must* be known at compile time and thus *must* be always fix <sup>*)</sup> – and so, in consequence is their size (must be...).

sizeof(c) will return this fixed size, even for containers, no matter how many elements you have placed in there, and this is why `sizeof(c)` is wrong (actually, it can never get 0, as mentioned by NathanOliver in his answer, but even if it could, it would be constantly 0 then even if the container was *not* empty).

To illustrate `sizeof`: Lets look at some standard containers (I'll leave out the public interface, just concentrate on the data members):

```
template <typename T>
vector
{
    size_t capacity;
    size_t size;
    T* data;
};
```

This is roughly all a vector needs. The data contained is stored in some array allocated somewhere on the heap, the only thing that is part of the vector *class* is the pointer to. `sizeof` such a vector is likely to be 32 (assuming size_t and pointers being 8 bytes large, as on modern 64 bit hardware, so you get 24 bytes for the members and another 8 for the pointer to the vtable, provided this vector class having virtual members) -- *constantly*.

```
template<typename T>
class list
{
    class Node
    {
       Node* next;
       Node* previous;
       T data;
    };
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
};
```

Again - two pointers internally only, content is allocated inside the nodes somewhere on the heap. `head` and/or `tail` *might* be some dummy nodes for easier use within `begin()` and `end()`, but if so, that's an implementation detail... sizeof(list) would then most likely be 24 -- constantly.

<sup>*)</sup>
"always fix" - during compile time and during runtime of your compiled program; sizes *can* vary if you compile for different machines (e. g. the vector and list above might have sizes of 16 and 12 if compiled for older 32 bit hardware). Sizes can even vary from one compilation to the other one e. g. due to changed compiler flags (e. g. changing default alignment, ...). But during compilation and once compiled, `sizeof` is fix.

Answer (score 7):

Why is `sizeof(c) == 0` wrong?  Every object must have an address which means it must have a size of 1 or more.  That means `sizeof(anything)` is always greater than `0`.  Because of that `sizeof(c) == 0` will never be true.

---

Also note that `sizeof` is a compile time operation.  It will not be able to give you the size of anything that is only known at run time.  For instance

```
char * foo = new char[20];
std::cout << sizeof(foo);
```

Will always give you the size of the pointer (4 or 8 on most platforms) and not the size of the memory the pointer points to.

Comment: Empty base classes have addresses too, it's just they might share that address with other subobjects.

Comment: @aschepler Good point.  I'll remove that

Comment: I would add that `sizeof()` is compile time size of object, you cannot use it to determine runtime information in any way.

Comment: While strictly true, this isn't really the reason why attempting to use `sizeof` for this task is wrong. The reason is that `sizeof` means a different thing.